# Get Path Of App Files

Tags: java, android, file

I am trying to get the directory of the app data files (/data/files)

How would I do this?

I tried `ContextWrapper.getFilesDir();` but it says `Non-static method 'getFilesDir()' cannot be referenced from a static context`

The context I am using it in is: `String[] filenames = ContextWrapper.getFilesDir();`
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is complaining regarding you need `context` instance to invoke `getFilesDir()`. If you're inside an `Activity`, you can just do.-

```
File[] files = getFilesDir().listFiles();
```

, as `Activity` itself is a `Context`. On the contrary, you'll need to pass `context` to the class that's gonna access the files directory.

Comment: So would It be String[] filenames = getFilesDir().listFiles()?

Comment: So close, it's actually a `File[]`. My bad, I'll edit my answer.